# how to call function variable in other one function

Tags: php, function, variables, joomla

I have created a new component for Joomla 2.5. I have two functions:

```
public function getBase(){

    if(JFactory::getUser()->guest) {
        $this->base = 'Гость';
    }
    else { 
        $user =& JFactory::getUser();
        $usr_id = $user->get('id');
        /**/

        $this->base = 'Гуд юзер id '.$usr_id.'';
        /*Get database info*/       
    }   

    return $this->base;
}

public function getGetInfo() {

    $this->getinfo = '11 '.$usr_id.''; 

    return $this->getinfo;
}
```

Please tell me how to use the `$usr_id = $user->get('id');` from `getBase()` in the `getGetInfo()` function. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these two functions are within the same class, then you can use a **class variable**.

```
class MyClass
{
    private $user;

    public function getBase()
    {
        // ---
        $user =& JFactory::getUser();

        // Set user class variable
        $this->user = $user;
        // ---
    }

    public function getGetInfo()
    {
        // Now you can use the user
        $user = $this->user;

        // ---
    }
}
```

As also explained above, you *can* (although you don't want to as it's code duplication), just call the same code in the `getGetInfo()` method to get the user. Don't duplicate your code though, use class variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have two option to achieve this requirement.

One is access it from the user object like same as above.

```
 $user =& JFactory::getUser();
 $user_id = $user->id;
```

Or you have to create a class variable for the class like

```
public $current_user;

and inside the  public function getBase(){ 

$this->current_user = $user->get('id'); 
}
```

then this `$this->current_user` variable will available in whole class functions